# How to grep file by another file's line using bash

Tags: bash

The file1 store Sentence want to grep,Here 's content file1

```
.|||anymore .
,|||arguments
,|||atheists
,|||be
,|||because the
.|||because the
```

The problem is **it contain space in some sentence** , and the target file2 contain the space too, how can I search all file2 content to know whether file2 has these sentence which in file1 or not

If found it  output grep result to anther file(append) ,If no found output a file to keep it

Comment: Show sample data from both files with your expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this-

```
while IFS= read -r i; do      #Reading the file line by line and saving lines in $i.
grep "$i" file2 >> output     #Grepping the line in the second file and outputting.
done < file1
```

Your question needs to be edited to give some more details though.

Comment: if can't find , how can I know what pairs can't find